# How can I generate weak SSH keys?

Tags: ssh-keys, rsa

I'm trying to put together a demonstration of the increasing difficulty of cracking SSH / RSA keys.

Ideally, I'd like to demonstrate cracking a 64-bit key, then a 128-bit, 256-bit, then, (possibly) a 512-bit, but never get to a 1024-bit, showing that the time increases drastically at each level.

However, `ssh-keygen` with the `-b` option seems to reject anything 512 and under as too small.

How can I deliberately generate weak keys?

Comment: In order to provide clarity?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Do they have to work with SSH specifically? And by "weak", you just mean short lengths, not other weaknesses like lack of entropy, correct?

Comment: You can always use [`PuTTYgen`](https://docs.joyent.com/jpc/getting-started-with-your-joyent-cloud-account/generating-an-ssh-key/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows) if you want a GUI Windows application.  Honestly its not clear what your trying to achieve.  If I use an extremely long passphrase on a 64-bit key, its going to be secure, beyond the fact it would simply be easier to generate an identical key with a passphrase I know.

Comment: @Ramhound Encrypting your SSH key on-disk with a long passphrase is irrelevant to the attack vector here. Breaking 330-bit RSA keys has been practical since 1991, and probably only takes a few minutes on a modern high-end desktop PC. For 512 bits, it's been practical since 1999 and now takes less than 10 days for a high-end desktop. 768 bits were broken in 2009, and it's within the realm of possibility that well-funded organizations could break a 1024-bit key today. NIST has deprecated or even disallowed 1024-bit RSA keys. 4096 bits is the current recommendation among InfoSec professionals.

Comment: I know that.  I wasn't sure what vector you were going after, not my expertise, but have knowlege in the area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openssl`'s `genrsa` subcommand can generate RSA key pairs as small as 64 bits. See `genrsa(1)`.

Comment: this doesn't work anymore (OpenSSL 3.0.2)